# android arraylist object populate Listview

Tags: android

I created an object that encapsulates all attributes of a discount. I have all objects inside the arraylist and now wish to create a listview. The listview row should have 2 attributes, name and city. How can this be achieved? Can I populate a listview with my arraylist of objects? When user clicks on row, it should take that object id and pass it to to next activity (via intent) to display more information. This is what I have now....

```
               for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);
                    DiscountObject discountObject = new DiscountObject();
                    discountObject.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    discountObject.city = jsonObject.getString("city");
                    discountObject.location = jsonObject.getString("location");
                    discountObject.rate = jsonObject.getString("rate");
                    discountObjectsList.add(discountObject);
                }
```

and this is my list definition:

private List discountObjectsList = new ArrayList();

Thanks and any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to create a custom list adapter to have your listview look/function the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Google for "android custom adapter listview", you will find tons of examples like [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html) one. Or [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/) one if you want to know a bit more about ListViews.